# simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Tags: json, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to send a http request to any url and get the response using urllib library. Following is the code that I have used :

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://www.youtube.com/results?bad+blood")
>>> r.status_code
    200
```

when I try to do this I get following error.

```
>>> r.json()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 808, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 516, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

can someone tell me whats wrong with the code.

PS: I am using python 2.7.10

Answer (score 2):

The response isn't JSON, it is `'text/html; charset=utf-8'`.  If you want to parse it, use something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

```
>>> import requests, bs4
>>> rsp = requests.get('http://www.youtube.com/results?bad+blood')
>>> rsp.headers['Content-Type']
'text/html; charset=utf-8'
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(rsp.content, 'html.parser')
```

I'd recommend using the YouTube Search API instead.  Log in to [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), set up a API key following the [API Key Setup instructions](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en&ref_topic=6262490), then you can make the request using the [YouTube Search API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list):

```
>>> from urllib import parse
>>> import requests
>>> query = parse.urlencode({'q': 'bad blood',
...                          'part': 'snippet',
...                          'key': 'OKdE7HRNPP_CzHiuuv8FqkaJhPI2MlO8Nns9vuM'})
>>> url = parse.urlunsplit(('https', 'www.googleapis.com',
...                         '/youtube/v3/search', query, None))
>>> rsp = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept': 'application/json'})
>>> rsp.raise_for_status()
>>> response = rsp.json()
>>> response.keys()
dict_keys(['pageInfo', 'nextPageToken', 'regionCode', 'etag', 'items', 'kind'])
```

Note that the example is using Python 3.  If you want to use Python 2, then you will have to import `urlencode` from `urllib` and `urlunsplit` from `urlparse`.

Answer (score 1):

That URL returns HTML, not JSON, so there's no point calling `.json()` on the response.